# Encoding in data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have an R data.table like below:

```
Date         Notes
12/2/2018   Car Serviced
12/4/2018   Purchased grocery
12/5/2018   Purchase fuel
```

I want to change the encoding of the `Notes` column.
I have the `Notes` column in a variable name.
So far have tried

```
Encoding(dt[[colname]])<-"UTF-8"

Error in `Encoding<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "UTF-8") : 
  a character vector argument expected

dt[, (colname):=enc2utf8(dt[,(colname)])]
```

Which unfortunately did not work either.

Also noticed that

```
class(dt[[colname]])
```

Is a factor...

Any thoughts on how I can achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try converting it from factor to character, and then trying to encode it?

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like:

```
setattr(dt[[colname]], "levels", enc2utf8(levels(dt[[colname]])))
```